# Caliburn.Micro MVVM WPF - enable a button when DataGrid has been edited by the user, otherwise disable it

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am new to MVVM and Caliburn.Micro.

I have implemented a DataGrid that is binded to `<BindableCollection><CustomerModel>` where CustomerModel is:

```
    public class CustomerModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public int HouseNumber { get; set; }
    public string ApartmentNumber { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

This data is loaded from XML file on startup and also can be saved into an XML file by clicking on a button "Save" which is connected to method SaveToXML() and obviously to CanSaveToXML(). Saving and loading works perfectly but I want to make the "Save" button enabled only if the user has edited the DataGrid, otherwise it should stay disabled.

I have tried comparing the current number of objects of CustomerModel class to the number of objects of CustomerModel at startup. If the number is different, it should enable the button as it indicates that someone has entered or deleted an entry.

```
        public bool CanSaveToXML()
    {
        if (CustomersOnStartup != Customers.Count())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

where

```
public BindableCollection<CustomerModel> Customers { get; set; }
```

The problem is that the Customers.Count() is executed only once and the number doesn't update after the startup and adding/deleting an entry by the user. I know that it is probably connected to

```
NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ???)
```

but I have no idea how to use it in relation to number of objects with Customers.Count()

Any ideas are welcome.

XAML implemenetation:

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>

    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Customers" AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Path=LastName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Street Name" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Path=StreetName}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="House Number" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Path=HouseNumber}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Apartment Number" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Path=ApartmentNumber}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Postal Code" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Path=PostalCode}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Town" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Path=Town}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Phone Number" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Path=PhoneNumber}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date of Birth" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Path=DateOfBirth}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Path=Age}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button x:Name="SaveToXML" Content="Save" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test the count number of the collection, you have to use a property which follows it:

```
    private int initcount;
    public YourViewModel()//constructor
    {
        RecordNbr = People.Count;
        initcount = RecordNbr;
    }

    //Property whixh follows the number of count
    private int _recordNbr;
    public int RecordNbr
    {
        get => _recordNbr;
        set
        {
            _recordNbr = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => RecordNbr);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanSaveToXML);
        }
    }

    public void SaveToXML()
    {

    }

    public bool CanSaveToXML
    {
        get => initcount == RecordNbr;
    }

    public void RemoveItem()
    {
       if (People.Count == 0) return;

        People.RemoveAt(0);
        RecordNbr = People.Count;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, althogh it still doesn't work. I don't get how RecordNbr can be updated everytime someone changes the number of Customers. Should I add it to the CustomerModel class as one of the parameters?

Comment: CustomerModel is the data..in my answer, RecordNbr is a property of viewmodel linked to the view,  where your method SaveToXml is defined. idont know the name of your view model,show your code where you remove or add

Comment: when you add or remove record, you have to set RecordNbr with the new value of count..have you seen my method RemoveItem in the sample

Comment: I know, I have seen it, it makes perfect sense, although I have no methods of removing or adding, as it is done just by DataGrid. My ViewModel is called MainViewModel.

Comment: so each time you have a count change , you have to set the property and the button will be enable or not.. if you work directly on datagrid, you have to find an event you could trap and set RecordNbr...its functional? then if you want to test the change of xml file you could use Hashcode, but only if your xml  is not too big..so ask new question if you dont know how to do..

Comment: to finalize the answer, dont forget to validate and upvote.